# Custom pin with alphanumeric representation in MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am now at a point of teaching myself the use of MapKit in Objective C.  I got to the point where I can autozoom to a location that contains several annotations.  I represent the annotations with the built in pins.  If you click on the pin I have a an alphanumeric 2 character string to represent that spot.

I thought to myself, for better usability, why not replace the pins with the actual data.  Kind of like a weathermap where they show the temperature as a pin.  Is this doable?

I researched this and all I could find is this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"];
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return annotationView;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot and should not have to have a custom image for each combination of the two characters.  Is there a way for me to draw these numbers at the location of the pin.

I found this reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html

Am I on the right track.  Are there some full examples I can leverage to better understand the flow.

I want to be able to select that custom pin however and segue or show more details.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes it's doable.  You don't have to use an image.  You can add a label subview with the text.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822756/replace-icon-pin-by-text-label-in-annotation/9823109#9823109 for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anna, thank you for the link, I tried it and it worked.  I made some changes to improve the esthetic of the label and I thought I would post my findings here for reference:

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

```
static NSString *reuseId = @"MapViewController";
MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
if (av == nil)
{
    av = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
    //UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];;
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  // This makes the background clear and just shows the text
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  // Use any colour you wish
    lbl.alpha = 1.0; //0.5;
    lbl.tag = 42;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0];   // This is optional, I found this fond and size most readable
    [av addSubview:lbl];

    //Following lets the callout still work if you tap on the label...
    av.canShowCallout = YES;
    av.frame = lbl.frame;
} else {
    av.annotation = annotation;
}

UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[av viewWithTag:42];
// I added this to the text to improve its visibility by essentially adding a stroke around the text.  Well its a poor man's stroke by adding a shadow
lbl.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
lbl.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
lbl.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
lbl.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;

lbl.text = annotation.title;

return av;
```

}